# Enlarge when surrounded by creatures

Tags: pathfinder-2e

Let's say a creature, X in the diagram, is surrounded by hostile creatures, the O's in the diagram, and on an otherwise infinitely flat and empty plane.

```
-+-+-+-+-
 | | | |
-+-+-+-+-
 |O|O|O|
-+-+-+-+-
 |O|X|O|
-+-+-+-+-
 |O|O|O| 
-+-+-+-+-
 | | | |
-+-+-+-+-
```

Creature X grows in size from some ability, such as [Enlarge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=102) or the reverse effect of [Shrink Down](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2905) or [Shrink](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=284). What happens? Do the other creatures get pushed out of the way? Does the effect fail (which could lead to a theoretically infinite Shrink spell)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's up to the GM

> **Moving Through a Creature's Space**
>
> If two creatures end up in the same square by accident, the GM
> determines which one is forced out of the square (or whether one falls
> prone). (Core Rulebook pg. 474 - [AoN](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=447))

In this case, they would either face forced movement, or fall prone. You could, technically, also force the Large creature out from between them.

Comment: ahhh that's a good rule spot, and it makes sense why it eluded my search (kept looking for "enlarge", "grow", and related terms). If no other answers come in soon with more specific rules or reasoning, then this does seem to be the right one!